# All IPv6 prefixes that should be routed by a public router

Tags: networking, ipv6, ip-address

I need a list of IPv6 prefixes that that cover the public internet with the fewest possible entries.

I´ve found the answer for IPv4 here: [IPv4 CIDR Ranges for Everything except RFC1918](https://serverfault.com/questions/304781/ipv4-cidr-ranges-for-everything-except-rfc1918)

The problem is I cannot blacklist prefixes. I need to whitelist them. Therefore I cannot just look what prefixes should be blocked (like RFC 4193 Unique Local Addresses (ULA)). I also don´t know much about IPv6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `2000::/3` prefix is where all of the Global Unicast addresses reside and may be what you want. There may be other prefixes you could add (but it seems unlikely) see [IPv6 Address Types](https://www.ripe.net/manage-ips-and-asns/ipv6/ipv6-address-types/ipv6addresstypes.pdf).

Comment: ... for now, this is likely to change some time in the future, and then all 2000::/3 configurations will cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

All Global IPv6 addresses are in the `2000::/3` range. There are a few ranges inside the Global address block that are not Globally Reachable.

See the *[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)*. There is a table, and one of the columns tells you if the range is Globally reachable or not.

There is also a similar *[IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)* for IPv4.